# .sort not working in firefox, but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects like:

```
  [
     {"type":"TEST", "submitted_on":null, "due_date": new Date(xxx) },
     {"type": "ESSAY", "submitted_on": new Date(xxx), "due_date":new Date(xxx)},
     {"type": "TEST", "submitted_on":new Date(xxx), "due_date": new Date(xxx)},
     {"type":"FILE", "submitted_on":new Date(xxx), "due_date":null}
  ]
```

I want to sort then in this order :

TEST type will have highest priority and will come first in order of due date earliest to latest if its submitted_on field is null. If it has a submitted_on entry it should be pushed to last. If no due date, it has lowest priority in due dates. After tests, all other types will be pushed next on the basis of due_date earliest to latest and those which have submitted_on field will always have lowest priority :

My sorting code:

```
  sortAssignments(assignments) {
    const sortedArray = assignments.sort((n1, n2) => {
      if (!n1.submitted_on && n2.submitted_on) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        if (n1.type === "TEST" && n2.type !== "TEST" && !n1.submitted) {
          return -1;
        } else if (n1.due_date < n2.due_date) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    });
    return sortedArray;
  }
```

This solution works in firefox and i have managed to return the array in sorted order , but in firefox , its returning an incorrect order . How to sort in this logic to make work on all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no symmetrical return result.

```js
const data = [{ type: "TEST", submitted_on: null, due_date: new Date('2020-05-02') }, { type: "ESSAY", submitted_on: new Date('2020-05-02'), due_date: new Date('2020-0-502') }, { type: "TEST", submitted_on: new Date('2020-05-02'), due_date: new Date('2020-05-02') }, { type:"FILE", submitted_on: new Date('2020-05-02'), due_date: null }];

data.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.type === 'TEST') - (a.type === 'TEST') ||
    (b.submitted_on === null) - (a.submitted_on === null) ||
    a.due_date - b.due_date
);

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type. Getting this error on -

Comment: just cast them to the wanted type. i have no idea of typescript.

Comment: - guess "-" wont work , should be a comparison operator

Comment: ok i added a '+'  +(b.type === "TEST") - +(a.type === "TEST") to convert to integer , it worked!! thanks

Comment: Don't do that, you need to cast the values to number using `<number>(b.type === "TEST") - <number>(a.type === "TEST")`. This is a typescript problem, not a JavaScript one